# How do I structure multiple Identity Data in a database

Tags: database, schema

Am designing a database for a credit bureau and am seeking some guidance.

The data they receive from Banks, MFIs, Saccos, Utility companies etc comes with various types of IDs. E.g. It is perfectly legal to open a bank account with a National ID and also a Passport. Scenario One that has my head banging is that Customer1 will take a credit facility (call it loan for now) in bank1 with the **passport** and then go to bank2 and take another loan with their **NationalID** and Bank3 with their **MilitaryID**. Eventually when this data comes from the banks to the bureau, it would be seen as 3 different people while we know that its actually 1 person. At this point, there is nothing we can do as a bureau.

However, one way out (for now) is using the Govt registry which provides a repository which holds both passports and IDS. So once we query for this information and get a response, how do I show in the DB that Passport_X is related to NationalID_Y and MilitaryNumber_Z?

Again, a person's name could be captured in various orders states. Bank1 could do FName, LName, OName while Bank3 can do LName, FName only. How do I store this names?

Even against one ID type e.g. NationalID, you will often find misspellt names or missing names. So one NationalID in our database could end up with about 6 different names because the person's name was captured different by the various banks where he has transacted.

And that is just the tip of the iceberg. We have issues with addresses, telephone numbers, etc etc.

Could you have any insight as to how I'd structure my database to ensure we capture all data from all banks and provide the most accurate information possible regarding an individual? Better yet, do you have experience with this type of setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I show in the DB that Passport_X is related to NationalID_Y and MilitaryNumber_Z?

Trivial.

You ahve an identity table, that has an AlternateId field if the Identity is linked to another one. Use the first IDentity you created as master. Any alternative will have AlternateId pointing to it.

You need to separate the identity from the data in it, so you can have alterante versions of it, possibly with an origin and timestampt. You need oto likely fully support versioning and tying different identities to each other as alternative, including generating a "master identity" possibly by algorithm with the "official" version of your data (i.e. consolidated).

The details are complex - mostly you ahve to make a LOT of compromises without killing performance, so at the end HIRE A SPECIALIST. There is a reason there are people out as sensior database designers or architects that have 20+ years experience finding the optimal solution given the constrints you may not even be aware of (application wise).

> Better yet, do you have experience with this type of setup?

Yes. Try financial information. Stock symbols / feeds / definitions are not necessariyl compatible and vary by whom you get it. Any non-trivial setup has different data feeds that may show the same item slightly different, sometimes in error. DIfferent name, sometimes different price (example: ES, CME group, is 50 USD per point, but on TT Fix it is 5 - to make up, the price is multiplied by 10, so instad of 1000.25 you get 10002.5). THis is the same line of consolidation, and it STINKS.

Tons of code, tons of proper database design, redoing it half a dozen time to get the proper performance. THis is tricky, sadly.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. And your right, the biggest headache of all is designing the DB without affecting performance. While we struggle with the DB, the coding guys are having hell with trying to sanitize the data sent without rejecting too much of it. I guess we'll just have to live with **redoing it half a dozen times.....** as there is no silver bullet.PS, thanks for the alternateID pointer.

Comment: In my world (financial) I have Instruments that have a Domain field. Domain is the "data domain" (bank, broker, whoever). They link to a MasterInstrumeent that HAS TO AHVE Domain at NULL - this is the "official internal master record for the entry" ;) It is often auto generated, sometimes manually. We consolidate all information (name etc.) and that is used INTERNALLY - you can then always look at how the instrument looks in other domains.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the ideas. One more thing which goes into speed and efficiency of the DB. I expect about 60million NationalIDS, and maybe about 20 million passports and several million MilitaryIDs. Should I have those in one table and have an ID type column or separate them into their respective tables? What would be your take?

Comment: Really depends. Identity table, Type field is enough - you can partition by type, so it is efficient to query. 100 million is nothing worth noting on a good server.